# Adding whitespaces to a multicolumn Listbox in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, whitespace, multiple-columns

I have a Listbox with two Columns in it and filling it that way:

```
            list.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}","header1","header2"));

            for (int i = 0; i < column1.Count;i++)
            {
                list.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", column1[i], column2[i]));
            }
```

What I want to do is putting whitespaces in it without doing it on my own (without making the gap bigger between {0} and {1}). So according to the length of the column items (column1 are numbers and column2 are strings) they should be in the middle of the "header1" and "header2" strings and there also should be a gap (let's say about 10 chars) between the headers. 
I know there is something like "PadRight" but don't know how to use that here. Is this possible? Thank you!

P.S.: I don't want to use a ListView

This should look like:

```
 "header1"          "header2"
     1                Name1
     3                Name2
     10               Name234
     101              Name10
```

Comment: PadRight will only really work if you are using a monospaced font. Are you sure it is a listbox you need and not a DataGrid?

Comment: Yes. But only if this is possible with Listboxes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment. Your on a downwards spiral if you start trying to massage data.... I've just searched on google for "columnar list box c#" and [this was the first result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which looks exactly like what you should be using (ListBox.MultiColumn property).. It even has an example

Comment: I tried this already "this.list.ColumnWidth = 85;" but it changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    list.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,20} {1,20}","header1","header2"));

    for (int i = 0; i < column1.Count;i++)
    {
        list.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,20} {1,20}", column1[i], column2[i]));
    }
```

Edit (Keep in mind that this is by no means optimal solution): 
If you want the values within columns to be closer to middle just add more spaces to the temp variable.

```
        string header1 = "Header_1";
        string header2 = "Header_2";
        int clmnWidth = 50;

        // Centered columns headers
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("|{0}|{1}|", 
                header1.PadLeft(clmnWidth / 2).PadRight(clmnWidth - header1.Length),
                header2.PadLeft(clmnWidth / 2).PadRight(clmnWidth - header2.Length)));

        string temp = "     ";
        for (int i = 0; i < clmn1.Length; i++)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("|{0}|{1}|", 
                temp + clmn1[i].ToString().PadRight(clmnWidth - clmn1[i].ToString().Length - temp.Length),    /*.PadLeft(clmnWidth / 2)*/
                temp + clmn2[i].ToString().PadRight(clmnWidth - clmn2[i].ToString().Length - temp.Length))); /*.PadLeft(clmnWidth / 2)*/
        }
```

Comment: That just shifts the strings and when I have a bigger integer it's completely broken.

Comment: You are welcome. P.S.: if u want the data within columns to be centered instead of left aligned, just use the commented part '.PadLeft(clmnWidth / 2)' and remove the 'temp +'

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it without Monospaced font is to use tab character:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("     " + column1[i] + "\t" + column2[i]);
```

But, a different control like `DataGridView` or `ListView` (or even two `ListBox` next to each other?) would be more flexible and easier to adjust.